# web3 alternative languages (aside from javascript)?

Tags: web3js

Are there any implementations of **web3** that are not in Javascript but preferably a compiled language with full multithreading support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost by definition, web3 is Javascript as it's a Javascript API to bind to a contract ABI (its public interface). However there are bindings for other languages, for example:

Go (as part of go-ethereum):
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts

HTTP:
https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#contract-api

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I was more or less looking at patching the client :)